# Does UTF-8 encoding have to be explicitly defined in a web service response?

Tags: c#, web-services, utf-8, asmx

I am supporting a C# (.asmx) web service built on .NET 3.5. It is a very, very simple service that returns, among a few other things, a street address. The scope of the application that provides the service was recently widened and now the DB behind it houses international addresses as well. This means Latin foreign language characters can be stored (accent marks, umlauts, etc) and consequently returned in a web service response.

When I test the service locally using soapUI's automatically generated requests and without adding any special headers or any other intstructive information, I see this element exactly as it's stored in the database - with its accent mark:

```
<CompositeStreet>140-146 RUE EUGÈNE DELACROIX</CompositeStreet>
```

However, when a connecting system calls the service the IT staff report that the response contains the question mark typically used as the replacement for a non-supported character:

```
<compositeStreet>140-146 RUE EUG?NE DELACROIX</compositeStreet>
```

**I'm unsure whose issue this is** and I'm concerned that the simplistic design of the service may mean that it falls on my shoulders to recode to somehow ensure any consumer is guaranteed to see the data in UTF-8 encoding. I've been under the impression that UTF-8 was the default encoding and nothing explicit was required. (Please save the discussion about upgrading to WCF for another thread - it's not in scope for this right now.)

Can you have a look at the structure of the service and tell me if there is actually something that needs to be done on my side? (Code drastically slimmed down for the sake of this discussion)

The ASMX page - basically the WebMethod accepts a request and returns the response:

```
namespace Company.IT.Network.LocationStore.LS_Services
{
    using . . .; 

   [WebService(Namespace = "Company.IT.Network.LocationStore.LS_Services.ClliRecordService")]
    public class ClliRecordService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        public ClliRecordService() { }

        [WebMethod(Description = "Lengthy description")]
        public VZBServiceResponse ClliLookup_VzbSite(VZBServiceRequest sRequest)
        {
            VZBServiceResponse sResponse = new VZBServiceResponse(sRequest);
            return sResponse;
        }
}
```

And the serializable class that is a property of the VZBServiceResponse type which ends up in the XML response. You'll see all there is is the `[Serializable]` attribute and the setting of the order of the elements returned.

```
namespace Company.IT.Network.LocationStore.LS_Lib.BO
{
    using ...;

    [Serializable]
    public class Address
    {
        private string _compositeStreet;
        private string _buildingName;

        [XmlElement(Order = 0)]
        public string BuildingName
        {
            get { return _buildingName; }
            set { _buildingName = value; }
        }

        [XmlElement(Order = 1)]
        public string CompositeStreet
        {
            get { return _compositeStreet; }
            set { _compositeStreet = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

There is really not much more to it than that. No formatting of the XML response through a memory stream (which I've seen in some posts) or specific handling through Serialize or Deserialize methods.

Are there recommendations to improve on this so that service consumers are guaranteed to be presented foreign language characters or is that really up to the calling system? Thank you for any guidance!

Comment: Why not create your own web service client ("Add Service Reference"), and call the service yourself to see if it returns the correct data?

Comment: Thanks @JohnSaunders - I probably will do that eventually, it's just a matter of finding the time in a deadline-driven do-less-with-more workday. I was hoping I didn't have to second-guess soapUI's result and that someone from experience would be able to answer the question of whether asmx web services default to UTF-8 encoding. After finding another couple of posts related to this topic, I'm heavily leaning toward "yes, they do" after some thorough reading but will certainly do what you suggested as soon as I'm able.

Comment: Do you realize that it should take you under an hour to create a client, call the service and see the result? See http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/, but you won't have to create a service because you already have one.